# ORDER BY issue in Select distinct case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(dpt.TrackId AS varchar(20)) + ' , ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), dpt.CreatedDate) AS TrackId  
FROM         
    ExcelUtilityTemplate 
INNER JOIN        
    DataImportProcessTracker dpt ON ExcelUtilityTemplate.TemplateId = dpt.TemplateId        
INNER JOIN
    TA_JDSU..Employee_Temp et ON et.TrackId = dpt.TrackId        
WHERE     
    (ExcelUtilityTemplate.ClientId = 'e0a94231-3265-4277-9cc3-236d9a2ead49' 
     AND et.RowStatus = 1) 
ORDER BY 
    dpt.CreatedDate desc
```

My above query throws the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I want to sort my records on the basis of `CreatedDate`.

Hoping for quick reply. Thanks

Comment: [The select documentation is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) `;with cte as ( select <rest of your query>) select * from cte order by dpt.CreatedDate desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify your query as follows:**

```
  SELECT distinct  Cast(dpt.TrackId as varchar(20)) +' , '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),dpt.CreatedDate) as TrackId ,dpt.CreatedDate
    FROM         ExcelUtilityTemplate INNER JOIN        
                          DataImportProcessTracker dpt ON ExcelUtilityTemplate.TemplateId = dpt.TemplateId        
                          inner join TA_JDSU..Employee_Temp et on et.TrackId=dpt.TrackId        
    WHERE     (ExcelUtilityTemplate.ClientId = 'e0a94231-3265-4277-9cc3-236d9a2ead49' and et.RowStatus=1) order by dpt.CreatedDate desc
```

**Explanation:**

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

When ever you are using distinct with select and ordering by some field. Then , That field should be included in your select clause

Hope this helps..

Comment: Means I just have to remove desc

Comment: @user3124690..just include what ever columns you are using in Order By in select clause. you are ordering by createdate and that is not a part of your select distinct. that is why it is throwing error. So, including that field in your select clause will eliminate your error.

Comment: @user3124690..its just typo error. See i am retrieving the field createddate along with what ever values you are fetching..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to order by the same value as you're doing `DISTINCT` on, since otherwise you may end up with more than one value to order by for each row;

```
SELECT distinct CAST(dpt.TrackId as varchar(20)) +' , '+ 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),dpt.CreatedDate) as TrackId  
FROM ExcelUtilityTemplate 
INNER JOIN DataImportProcessTracker dpt 
  ON ExcelUtilityTemplate.TemplateId = dpt.TemplateId        
INNER JOIN TA_JDSU..Employee_Temp et 
  ON et.TrackId=dpt.TrackId        
WHERE (ExcelUtilityTemplate.ClientId = 'e0a94231-3265-4277-9cc3-236d9a2ead49' 
  AND et.RowStatus=1) 
ORDER BY CAST(dpt.TrackId as varchar(20)) +' , '+ 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),dpt.CreatedDate) DESC
```